# Wi-Fi antenna seems to work when the device is off

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, android-versions, bugs

When I was looking at battery statistics I've found something strange: the bar showing wether a component is running or not indicates that wifi were active when I took off my phone. Is this a bug?
I have a Google Nexus 5 with standard Android 5 on it.

Here the screenshot of statistics :
[image: Wi-Fi working when Android device is off]

Answer (score 1):

As *Microsoft*) used to say:

> That's not a bug, that's a feature.

Check for following: `Settings` -> `Wi-Fi` -> `Menu` -> `Advanced`:

- Scanning always available
- Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep

Comment: OK thanks so when my device is set off it's "sleeping"?

Comment: @Daair sleeping and being switched off are two different things.